# Does PHP store sessions individually or in shared memory?

Tags: javascript, php, memory, redis, session-cookies

Suppose that I have a website that writes to a database upon starting it. If multiple users sign onto this website at the same time, does that imply that it will try to write to the database N times, where N = the # of users? Is there any way to force PHP to only write to the database if the connections are disconnected (only write if all other users are currently not on the website)? What would you suggest to be a way to reduce the possibly of excessive writes or requests to the database?

Comment: Depends on server configuration, but the default settings for PHP are to write sessions to files on the hard drive, not to a database.

Comment: `Is there any way to force PHP to only write to the database if the connections are disconnected (only write if all other users are currently not on the website)?` - I hardly doubt it.  How is the server going to keep track of all the pending data that needs to be inserted later on?  Lets say there are 1M users data that need to be inserted later on.  As far as I am concerned, the data insertion has to be immediate.

Answer (score 0):

To start, PHP defaults to session files. These files are created at the first `session_start();` call per browser (aka user). After that the same file is used for subsequant `session_start();` for a user until they close their browser. However session files are not cleared from the server when clients close the browser as they have a lifetime defined by PHP.

If you are trying to decide if all sessions have expired (no clients have connected since all sessions expired) you will need to clear out session files that the PHP garbage collector hasn't found yet, scan the session directory for any files, and if a session file does not exist in the directory you can assume there are no active users on the site.

Note that if you are using an in-memory module, for example: `php-redis` to store sessions, the route needed to check for sessions needs to be changed from files to whichever handler is being used to check for sessions.